# Is there an IIS-compatible OSS web app that can be used to serve static content + record stats?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, statistics, windows-server

What I am interested in:

1. Serving small static content (JS/CSS/fonts/small images/etc). All easily cacheable, no streaming. Basically things that people often put on CDNs. Upload support is not required.
2. Recording some basic statistics (at least access counts per Referer and last access time per Referer), and being able to see them in a Web UI.
3. Potentially blocking hotlinking (some rules around who can request content), but this is optional.

That has to run on Windows Server + IIS.

Comment: Why should it be a web app? You could create a static page and get some referer with google analytics for example. Or do you need some kind of cloud based file hosting like ownCloud?

Comment: @Matthias I can't get referrer for CSS/JS files using Google Analytics, only for HTML files. What I need is to serve CSS/JS files (similar to CDN), so that developers can reference them in their web apps, then get referer information for those files (to see which applications use a given JS library, for example).